# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT Query

Tags: mysql

I need the code below to only have the highest/most recent amount of TotalRentDays for each car, instead of repeating them until it gets down to zero. The screenshot shows that the table is outputting every time a car reaches another day rented, such as CarId 15. When I put DISTINCT into the query it only made the first entry, CarId 2, not repeat.

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdUOd.png)

```
SELECT DISTINCT CarId, Make, Model, (NumOfRentDays) AS TotalRentDays FROM Cars
JOIN Rents ON Cars.CarId= Rents.Cars_CarId ORDER BY TotalRentDays DESC;
```

Comment: You need max(date_rented) and max(number of days) with group by CarId, Make, Model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `max` on `NumOfRentDays` and then `group` the entire result set by `carid`.

Should look something like this :

```
SELECT CarId, Make, Model, max(NumOfRentDays) AS TotalRentDays FROM Cars
JOIN Rents ON Cars.CarId= Rents.Cars_CarId  GROUP BY CarId ORDER BY TotalRentDays DESC;
```